# round sql integer to nearest hour

Tags: sql, excel, integer

I have a column formatted as an integer (values ex. 2300, 0040, 2090) with values representing military time.  What would be the easiest way to round these values to the nearest hour?  So, if 2330, would round up to 2400, etc.  I don't want the values converted to date/time.

I'm looking for help in either SQL or Excel.   Thanks.

Comment: Is the column int or varchar?  Because 0040 does not seem to be an integer.

Comment: Do you want nearest hour, or to always round up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple arithmetic.  Most SQL dialects support `floor()`:

```
select floor((col+70) / 100) * 100
```

In Excel, you would use:

```
select floor((col+70) / 100, 1) * 100
```

You still have an issue with 0000 and 2400.  If that is an issue, then you would need to use conditional logic or modulo arithmetic.

Comment: What's the issue with 0000 and 2400? Those values seem to work fine when I test your logic.

Comment: @Goat_CO . . . They represent the same time.  The OP uses them as examples in the question, so I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought you were saying the logic didn't round them properly, which I guess technically it doesn't, but if they allow for both they've got bigger issues.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much Gordon.  I knew it shouldn't be a difficult solution.  The floor function will come in handy for me elsewhere as well.