# convert a number to hours (ROUND issue)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a number to hours.. my code is doing that, but is not 100% right.
the number 2.98 is 2 hours and 0.98*60 = 58,8 minutes.. I want round this minutes to 59
I want my result in my code +02:59, and it without this little round is +02:58.

Anyone knows how to round a time in my code?

```
DECLARE @number_hours FLOAT = 2.98

--if number is negative
IF(@number_hours) < 0
BEGIN
    SET @number_hours = @number_hours*-1
    PRINT '-'+ CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(DATETIME, @number_hours/24), 108)
END
ELSE
    PRINT '+'+ CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(DATETIME, @number_hours/24), 108)
```

Comment: Can hours exceed 23? 24 hours would yield 00:mm with this approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [round sql integer to nearest hour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195603/round-sql-integer-to-nearest-hour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to round to the nearest minute, you need to round your fractional number of hours to the nearest minute first, so something like:

```
DECLARE @number_hours FLOAT = 2.98

--if number is negative
IF(@number_hours) < 0
BEGIN
    SET @number_hours = @number_hours*-1
    PRINT '-'+ CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(DATETIME, ROUND(@number_hours * 60, 0)/(24.0 * 60)), 108)
END
ELSE
    PRINT '+'+ CONVERT(varchar(5), CONVERT(DATETIME, ROUND(@number_hours * 60, 0)/(24.0 * 60)), 108)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @f [real]
SET @f = 2.98

SELECT DATEADD(mi, (@f - FLOOR(@f)) * 60, 
                                  DATEADD(hh, FLOOR(@f), CAST ('00:00:00' AS TIME)))
```

**Output** :- 02:58:00.0000000

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to fix it with a mathematical calculation:

```
select 2.98
       + iif
         ( 2.98 % (1/60.0) > 0 -- check if remainder > 0
         , (1/60.0) - 2.98 % (1/60.0) -- round up
         , 0 -- it's already rounded, keep it as is
         )
```

It takes the remainder of the division with a minute. If more than 0, it rounds up.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use this one :

```
DECLARE @number_hours FLOAT = 2.98
DECLARE @HOUR NUMERIC
DECLARE @MIN NUMERIC
DECLARE @FORIF FLOAT = @number_hours


SET @number_hours = CASE WHEN @number_hours<0 THEN @number_hours*-1 ELSE @number_hours END
SET @HOUR = ROUND(@number_hours,1)
SET @MIN = (1-(@HOUR-@number_hours))*60


IF(@FORIF) < 0
BEGIN
    PRINT '-'+CONVERT(varchar,@HOUR-1)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROUND(@MIN,0))
END
ELSE
    PRINT '+'+ CONVERT(varchar,@HOUR-1)+':'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,ROUND(@MIN,0))
```